# Ruby on Rails: Creating child objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, parent-child

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I'm just a newbie so...

I have a model, Game, which `has_many :piles`. Pile, in turn, `has_many :cards`. I'm able to populate the Piles and Cards at creation of the Game, so my code at present looks something like:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :piles

  def after_create
    1.upto(4) do |num|
      Pile.new("game_id" => id, "contents" => "c_type_#{num}")
    end
  end
end

class Pile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards
  belongs_to :game

  def after_create
    1.upto(10) do |num|
      Card.new("pile_id" => id, "value" => num)
    end
  end
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pile
end
```

Now this is all very well, but it feels wrong to be passing `"game_id" => id` when ActiveRecord *knows* that game_id is the foreign key and should refer to the parent game. But if I leave it off, the foreign key ends up unset. Is there a better way to do this?

(For a bonus, probably simpler, question; suppose Game also `has_one :monkey`. How best do I create the monkey from within the Game model?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Pile.new("game_id" => id, "contents" => "c_type_#{num}")
```

try:

```
piles.create("contents" => "c_type_#{num}")
```

It tries saving the created pile straight away. Or, if you *really* need that no saving takes place (which is the case with `create`), you can do:

```
new_pile = piles.build("contents" => "c_type_#{num}")
```

Similar for the Pile class and its cards.

As for `has_one :monkey`, you can do the following (from within a method of Game):

```
create_monkey("some_attr" => "some_value")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Game` object's `piles` association collection will have `build` and `create` methods provided by Active Record (the `create` method also saves the associated object assuming it passes validation).

You should be able to do something like this:

```
def after_create
  1.upto(4) do |num|
    piles.create(:contents => "c_type_#{num}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others have said, you should consider viewing this [week's railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) - which deals with inherited resources in Rails 2.3, specifically in views.

Part 2 should appear next monday (2010-01-18)